# In what sense does analyticity guarantee the following equality?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, cauchy-principal-value

I was reading a paper$^1$ on particle physics, and at some point it is stated that, provided $f(x)$ is analitic, we have
$$
f(x)-f(0)=\frac{x}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{Im}\;f(y)}{y(y-x-i\varepsilon)} \;\mathrm dy\tag{1}
$$
where the $i\varepsilon$ is supposed to be taken $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ after integrating.

This looks very similar to (what we physicists) call the [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations), though I believe in mathematics it is called the [Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem):
$$
\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x-i\varepsilon}\mathrm dx=i\pi f(0)+\mathcal P\!\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm dx \tag{2}
$$
where $\mathcal P$ means Cauchy principal value.

**My questions**: is the relation $(1)$ true in general? under what circumstances? is it possible to prove $(1)$ from $(2)$? or is $(2)$ irrelevant here?

---

$^1$ *The Muon g-2*, by F. Jegerlehner and A. Nyffelerpage, [arXiv:0902.3360v1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.3360.pdf), page 39.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I was able to prove this myself:

Write the Kramers-Kronig relations as
$$
\text{Re}\; g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathcal P\int \frac{\text{Im}\;g(y)}{y-x} \mathrm dy
$$

Using the Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem, namely
$$
\mathcal P\int \frac{\text{Im}\;g(y)}{y-x} \mathrm dy=\int \frac{\text{Im}\;g(y)}{y-x-i\varepsilon} \mathrm dy-i\pi\  \text{Im}\; g(x)
$$
we find
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{\text{Im}\;g(y)}{y-x-i\varepsilon} \mathrm dy
$$

Finally, by taking $g(x)\equiv (f(x)-f(0))/x$ we get the expression in the OP. The answer to the question "*under what assumptions*" is: we must have $\text{Im}\;f(0)=0$.